# Is there way to fix the camera Functionality onto iOS using flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

The problem is accessing the camera on iPhone does not work. Trying access the camera on Android does work. Im building app using flutter which Im trying to make the app functional for both device. Every time I press on camera button. The app exit by itself. Im trying to send this picture to the firebase database. Doing this way won't let me access camera functionality for iOS.

I have tried to eliminate photo library functionality but that did not work. Camera before was working. The camera dependency is in Pubspec.yaml

```
Future getImage() async {
    var tempimage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      sampleimage = tempimage;

    });
  }
    Future getLibraryImage() async {
    var libraryimage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      sampleimage = libraryimage;

    });
    }

shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
                  onPressed: () { getImage(); },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(" Camera "),
                      Image.asset("images/camera.png", height: 15.0,),
                  ],
                  ),
                ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Have you included the required camera access privacy strings into the iOS Info.plist file?

Comment: Yes, I think my problem I never included it there. Now it works

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask the permission to the user for using the camera. 
For that, you can add these lines in `Info.plist` file in `ios/Runner`

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Using the library for ...</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Using the mic for ...</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Using the camera for ...</string>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added it two lines Privacy in the Xcode info.list